# How to copy an AMI from Ireland region to China region in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have a setup in AWS Ireland region, now I want that AMI in my China.
Does anybody know what is the best practice to achieve the task?

Comment: What is wrong with this: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/03/12/announcing-ami-copy-for-amazon-ec2/

Comment: It is China this doesn't work there

Comment: As of April it is possible : https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/amazon-ec2-allows-copy-amazon-machine-images-across-aws-govcloud-aws-china-other-regions/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AMI copy is currently not supported for China region.

According to AWS: [Transfer or copy AMI from US to China (Beijing)](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=697046)

> The idea is to create a dump file of the volume using 'dd', copy the
>   file to a temporary instance in China Region. Once copied, use dd
>   again to dump the contents of the file to an EBS volume. Then create a
>   snapshot of the EBS volume which contains the data and create an AMI
>   out of it.
>
> You may refer an over view of the process below:
>
> 1. Launch a linux instance in the AWS Region then use "dd” command to save the instance’s whole root volume as a file to a secondary EBS
>      volume.
>
> `mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf`
>
> `mount /dev/xvdf /mnt`
>
> `dd if=/dev/xvda of=root.img bs=1M`
>
> 2. Copy the file to an instance in cn-north-1 region.
>
> `scp -i key.pem root.img ec2-user@<ip_address>:/tmp`
>
> 3. In that cn-north-1 region’s instance, use ‘dd’ command to write that file to an EBS volume
>
> `dd if=/tmp/root.img of=/dev/xvdf bs=1M oflag=direct`
>
> 4. Delete the keypair on the volume, where`{cloud username}` is 'ubuntu' for ubuntu, 'ec2-user' for Amazon Linux, 'admin' for Debian, 'core' for CoreOS/Container Linux
>
> `mkdir -p /tmp/volume`
>
> `partprobe`
>
> `mount /dev/xvdf1 /tmp/volume`
>
> `rm /tmp/volume/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
>
> `rm /tmp/volume/home/{cloud username}/.ssh/authorized_keys`
>
> `umount /tmp/volume`
>
> 5. Create a snapshot of the volume, refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html).
> 6. Create an AMI from the snapshot, refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html#creating-launching-ami-from-snapshot).
> 7. Finally, use that AMI to launch an instance, which is the same as the instance running in the original AWS region.
>
> NB=Please note that in some cases, you might need to update
>   /etc/fstab, grub configuration files etc. with the label of the new
>   volume.

Comment: I'm not sure that people that have upvoted have tried this. The SCP speed hit ~50kB/s after 40MB that makes any large image almost impossible to transfer.