# How can Switch AWS EC2 server instance from one country to another country

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS server instance and i have deployed my application in AWS India origin cause of latency issue i wish to switch AWS china. So as i read about "Amazon Machine Image" but i am not sure about it would work or not.

Does cross origin copy of AWS AMI support in china?

I am little bit confuse about as below link is showing AWS EBS is there so my question is   Do we use AWS-EBS service to create an AMI image?

https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/ebs/

Comment: This helped someone at my work:
https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/migrating-aws-resources-to-a-new-region/
Maybe it can help you too.

Comment: I am not sure that would be work or not. Are you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy an AMI from Ireland region to China region in AWS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461042/how-to-copy-an-ami-from-ireland-region-to-china-region-in-aws)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a AMI from existing instance and launch a new instance from that AMI in the new region. You need to copy the AMI to new region before starting the new instance.

For detailed steps see [this blog](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/how-to-move-amazon-ec2-to-different-availability-zone-vpc-region/)

Comment: So AMI service would copy the same infrastructure image of server right and we can create the same server instance in another country. Is it?

Comment: yes @atuljain, The purpose of creating Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is to replicate the instance. So you can create a AMI and replicate/scale your services/instances.